# Closing AdMob interstitial destroys activity I called it from

Tags: android, admob

When I close the AdMob interstitial test-ad, the activity I called it from gets destroyed. I create the interstitial like this:

```
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(MY_TEST_DEVICE_HASHED_ID)
    .build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            System.out.println("AD getting closed");
        }
    });

    public void show_ad() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) interstitialAd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("onDestroy() called");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

LogCat output:

```
07-27 14:39:35.348: I/Ads(5699): Ad opening.
07-27 14:39:35.438: I/chromium(5699): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-27 14:39:35.498: I/chromium(5699): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-27 14:39:35.498: E/qdutils(5699): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
07-27 14:39:45.659: D/dalvikvm(5699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3174K, 23% free 11067K/14272K, paused 21ms, total 23ms
07-27 14:39:48.612: I/Ads(5699): Ad closing.
07-27 14:39:48.612: I/System.out(5699): AD getting closed
07-27 14:39:48.622: I/System.out(5699): onDestroy() called
```

Why is the activity getting destroyed?

Comment: I can't see any reason it should. I'd guess the error is somewhere else. What is your console output?

Comment: Updated my question with LogCat output

Comment: I'd investigate where the `onDestroy` is called from. There's no reason the interstitial should destroy your entire Activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  I added `|screenSize` to `android:configChanges` of the activity and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but Solution that worked for me :
i just added `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`  in  AdActivity of my manifest.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```